# JDO Relationships - App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdo

I'd like to implement a simple category system for my recipes.

Here's my Recipe entity:

```
@PersistenceCapable
public class Recipe {
    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    private Key key;
    @Persistent
    private List<Category> categories;

    public Recipe(List<Category> categories) {
        this.categories = categories;
    }
    ...
}
```

And my Category entity:

```
@PersistenceCapable
public class Category {
    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    private Key key;
    @Persistent
    private String name;

    public Category(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    ...
}
```

Now as you can see the association is simple. When I create a `Recipe` I make sure I construct it with a list of categories. This is great. On my site I can just iterate over a `Recipe` list (or whatever) and then just do `.getCategories()` on it to retrieve the categories I need.

However, say I want to retrieve all categories in the datastore and when I click on one category I want to be able to retrieve all recipes for that category. What's the easiest to go about this?

To show all categories I have: `select from Category.class group by name`.
But how do I retrieve all the recipes under a given category? Is my design flawed for JDO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SELECT FROM mydomain.Recipe WHERE category = :category

Don't know what is this "flawed for JDO" idea ... JDO simply provides transparent persistence and lets you design your classes as you want.

Comment: `WHERE category = :category` - I don't have a `category` field in my `Recipe` class.

Comment: SELECT FROM mydomain.Recipe WHERE categories.contains(:category) returns all Recipes which contain a particular Category.

Comment: Ok, but what is `:category`? A category object? A category key?

Comment: In Java when you type collField.contains(element) what is element ? something contained in the collection. A Category of course. That is the whole point of JDOQL, it follows Java

Comment: `:category` is a place-holding word that you define when you call `execute` on a `Query`.

Comment: @DataNucleus: The issue is that I will most likely need to filter recipes based on the category **name** and not the category object itself. Will I need to fetch the Category object from the name and then use it with .contains() on the recipe collection?

Comment: How would you do it in Java? add a variable for the category, so the query becomes SELECT FROM mydomain.Recipe WHERE categories.contains(theCategory) && theCategory.name = :name